# rspec .to receive(:method_name) correct usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

reduced code:

```
class Object
  def foo
    (bar / 100).round(2)
  end

  def bar
    self.some_integer
  end
end
```

I wanted to test that foo calls bar so my spec looks like this

```
it 'calls #bar upon self' do
  expect(@object).to receive(:bar)
  @object.foo
end
```

Unfortunately the spec then fails because when calling `@object.foo` the `#bar` is nil and fails on the division. Its impossible that `#bar` returns a nil value thats ensured before.
How do I test this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare which `bar` value you're expecting for this test:

```
expect(@object).to receive(:bar).and_return(10)
```

[Docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/configuring-responses/returning-a-value)

**EDIT**

you can also (thanks @meta):

```
expect(@object).to receive(:bar).and_call_original
```

Comment: Yep that works. just did the math myself and added the `return`. From the lingo I was guessing that it just checks of the method gets called on the object. Thanks

Comment: you can also use `and_call_original` instead of `and_return` if you don't want to alter the original behavior of `foo`.